# Paypal IPN sample code has no ActionResult. How am i meant to give a url if there is no view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

This is paypals sample code for the ipn. I have been on it for a few days now and am getting no where. I am not sure what i am meant to call. In a previous question i asked some said you dont call the Receive method. So this then lead me on to think how will Paypal know where to go. (i.e what method to use.)

```
public class IPNController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult Receive()
    {
        //Store the IPN received from PayPal
        LogRequest(Request);

        //Fire and forget verification task
        Task.Run(() =>  VerifyTask(Request));

        //Reply back a 200 code
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    private void VerifyTask(HttpRequestBase ipnRequest)
    {
        var verificationResponse = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var verificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

            //Set values for the verification request
            verificationRequest.Method = "POST";
            verificationRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var param = Request.BinaryRead(ipnRequest.ContentLength);
            var strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

            //Add cmd=_notify-validate to the payload
            strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;
            verificationRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

            //Attach payload to the verification request
            var streamOut = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();

            //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
            var streamIn = new StreamReader(verificationRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            verificationResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();

        }
        catch ( Exception exception)
        {
            //Capture exception for manual investigation
        }

        ProcessVerificationResponse(verificationResponse);
    }


    private void LogRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        // Persist the request values into a database or temporary data store
    }

    private void ProcessVerificationResponse(string verificationResponse)
    {
        if (verificationResponse.Equals("VERIFIED"))
        {
            // check that Payment_status=Completed
            // check that Txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that Receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that Payment_amount/Payment_currency are correct
            // process payment
        }
        else if (verificationResponse.Equals("INVALID"))
        {
            //Log for manual investigation
        }
        else
        {
            //Log error
        }
    }
}
```

There is no ActionResult so how am i meant to give a URL.
I thought of this but it seems to return invalid

```
public ActionResult IPN() {
    Receive()


}
```

I have asked previous questions but still cant seem to get my head around this IPN.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that sees this, this was an inexperienced me and all i had to do was
return Ok() so my action result would look like the below:

```
public ActionResult IPN() 
{
    Receive();  
    return Ok();
}
```